# Using gmaps4rails my long and lat co-ords are out a little and I'm not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm setting some locations on the map in my website. I go to google maps and get co-ordinates of the places I want. Then I put these numbers into my longitude and latitude fields to position the marker. I check the map on my site and the markers are out by a small amount and I don't understand it.

I hold the values for longitude and latitude in floats.

this is the difference in location

Here is google maps 
[image]

and this is where my marker is placed
[image]

you can see that its out by a good bit but I have put the longitude and latitude directly from google maps, so it should appear here.

here is my controller code

```
def show
@store = Store.all
@json = Store.all.to_gmaps4rails do |store, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/stores/infowindow", :locals => { :store => store})
  marker.json ({:title => store.title})
  marker.json ({:latitude => store.latitude})
  marker.json ({:longitude => store.longitude})
  marker.json ({:street_line_one => store.street_line_one})
  marker.json ({:street_line_two => store.street_line_two})
  marker.json ({:town => store.town})
  marker.json ({:county => store.county})
  marker.json ({:opening_hours=>store.opening_hours})
  marker.json ({:phone_no=>store.phone_no})
  marker.json ({:email=>store.email})
  marker.picture ({
    'picture'=>view_context.image_path("map_marker.png"),
    'width'=>79,
    'height'=>74
    })
end
```

and here is the model code

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gmappable

  attr_accessible :id, :street_line_one, :latitude, :longitude, :street_line_two, :town, :county, :country, :gmaps, :title, :opening_hours, :mainpage_images, :phone_no, :email

  def gmaps4rails_address
      "#{latitude}, #{longitude}"
  end
end
```

I don't understand why my markers aren't falling in exactly the same place as google maps.

any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- use the latest version of the gem where default offset is null
- or: `handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });`

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your input as creator of the gem, its been a really great help.I'm much much closer now that I have updated the gem.
but the marker still wont go exactly where the store is.
Is there any reason that the marker would stick to roads?

Comment: nope check the coordinates you pass. Maybe db removes some of your precision

Comment: yeah you were spot on, my database is knocking off the very last decimal point of the coordinates, I'm guesing I can fix this by changing to a decimal instead of a float or messing around with the DB. Thanks apneadiving :D